# Deleting packages from Gitlab repo when no reference is available in projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, gitlab

For one of my solution, I do have certain packages in packages folder. Need to remove them from the folder as they cause issue with inclusive language though no other issue on compatibility or functionality having the packages in place. Those packages are not used in any of the projects in solution and have no reference for them  from any project is available.

What is the way to delete or remove them from the repository? Don't find any option from gitlab. As it those packages are not referred from projects, so package manager does not help.

Using Gitlab and Visual Studio 19. project is on dotnet code 3.1.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what should be done. Can you clarify please - you need to delete some files from your git repo itself or you need to delete some files before one of your pipeline's jobs are running? or something else?

Comment: Hi Egor, I want to delete files from gitlab. those files are not used in any of the projects we have and have no reference to them from the projects